# RecyclerView многосоставной

Tags: java, android-studio, recyclerview, adapter, recyclerview.adapter

Нужно реализовать RecyclerView в котором должен быть заголовок и под ним список который зависит от данных БД. По началу сделал несколько RecyclerView на одном активити но считаю это не правильно и сжирает много данных.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему бы вам не реализовать один Adapter с несколькими viewHolder. В интернете много инфы найдете. Из плюсов что у вас может быть сколько угодно этих заголовков))

Comment: я читал об этом, но мне не понятно то что по заголовком у меня картинки их может быть от 1 до 20. Как бы я умею создавать такие списки с заголовками и картинками, но проблема в том что картинки не фиксированные (имеется в виду по количеству). Я просто не знаю куда копать в плане поиски инф.

Comment: Это ничего страшного. Вы создаете для них общий интерфейс, который будет содержать Enum. И он будет определять какой элемент показывать. 
И если вам нужно чтоб картинки выкладывались не по одной в ряд, это тоже можно реализовать через gridLayout. В общем, через час я могу скинуть пример как реализовано такая же задача

Comment: ок, спасибо, буду ждать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример будет на `Kotlin`. У вас не должно возникнуть проблем

Я использую базовый `Adapter` и `ViewHolder`

BaseAdapter

```
abstract class BaseAdapter<E,
    H : BaseListViewHolder<E>>(val context: Context?, val listener: BaseItemClickListener<E>?)
: RecyclerView.Adapter<H>() {

val items = mutableListOf<E>()

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return items.size
}

fun addItem(item: E) {
    items.add(item)
    notifyItemInserted(itemCount - 1)
}

fun addItems(items: List<E>) {
    this.items.addAll(items)
    notifyItemInserted(itemCount - 1)
}

fun updateItems(items: List<E>) {
    if (this.items != items) {
        clearAdapter()
        addItems(items)
    }
}

fun clearAdapter() {
    items.clear()
    notifyDataSetChanged()

   }

        interface BaseItemClickListener<E> {
            fun onItemClick(item: E)
        }
    }
```

ViewHolder

```
abstract class BaseListViewHolder<T>(itemView: View, private val listener: BaseItemClickListener<T>?)
: RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {

val context = itemView.context

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
override fun onClick(view: View) {
    listener?.onItemClick(view.tag as T)
}

   open fun bindData(item: T) {
        itemView.tag = item
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
    }
}
```

Теперь посмотрим сам Адаптер. Обратите внимание на метод `onCreateViewHolder` здесь определяет какой `ViewHolder` будет использоваться

```
class TestAdapter(context: Context?, listener: BaseItemClickListener<Cvodka>)
    : BaseAdapter<Cvodka, BaseListViewHolder<Cvodka>>(context, listener) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BaseCvodkaViewHolder {
        return when (viewType) {

            EnumCvodka.HEADER.id ->
                HeaderItemCvodkaViewHolder(getInflatedItemView(R.layout.item_cvodka_header, parent), listener)

            EnumCvodka.ACHIEVEMENT.id ->
                AchievementTestViewHolder(getInflatedItemView(R.layout.item_achievements, parent), listener)

            else ->
                HeaderItemCvodkaViewHolder(getInflatedItemView(R.layout.item_cvodka_header, parent), listener)
        }

    }

    private fun getInflatedItemView(@LayoutRes layoutId: Int, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layoutId, parent, false)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BaseListViewHolder<Cvodka>, position: Int) {
        holder.bindData(items[position])
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return items[position].getType().id
    }
}
```

Для него нам нужен базовый ViewHolder. От него будут наследоваться другие ViewHolder-ы

```
abstract class BaseCvodkaViewHolder(itemView: View, listener: BaseAdapter.BaseItemClickListener<Cvodka>?)
    : BaseListViewHolder<Cvodka>(itemView, listener)
```

Сам AchievementTestViewHolder

```
class AchievementTestViewHolder(itemView: View, listener: BaseAdapter.BaseItemClickListener<Cvodka>?)
    : BaseCvodkaViewHolder(itemView, listener) {

    override fun bindData(item: Cvodka) {
        super.bindData(item)

        val model = item as AchievementTestModel

        val image = if(model.medal.medal.image == null) model.medal.options.last().imageBig else model.medal.medal.image
        ImageUtils.loadAttachmentImage(context, image, itemView.equipmentImage)

    }
}
```

Интерфейс `Cvodka` будет по сути общим типом, список с ним мы будем передавать.

```
interface Cvodka {
    fun getType() : EnumCvodka
}
```

EnumCvodka нужен нам чтоб определить тип объекта

```
enum class EnumCvodka(val id: Int) {
HEADER(0, ACHIEVEMENT(1)
```

}

Сам AchievementTestModel может выглядеть так

```
class AchievementTestModel(var medal : AchievementModel) : Cvodka {
    override fun getType(): EnumCvodka {
        return EnumCvodka.ACHIEVEMENT
    }
}
```

В вашем фрагменте в `onViewCreated`

```
  val gridlayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity, MAX_SPAN_COUNT)

    gridlayoutManager.spanSizeLookup = object : GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        override fun getSpanSize(position: Int): Int {
            return when (adapter.getItemViewType(position)) {

                EnumCvodka.HEADER.id -> 12
                EnumCvodka.ACHIEVEMENT.id -> if (resources.configuration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
                    resources.getInteger(R.integer.content_dostizenie_h) else resources.getInteger(R.integer.content_dostizenie_v)
                else -> 12
            }
        }
    }
    recyclerView.layoutManager = gridlayoutManager
```

Возможно у вас появился вопрос как создать `List<Cvodka>`

Это может быть что-то вроде такого

```
val lists = arrayListOf<Cvodka>()
lists.add(HeaderItemModelCvodka(achievementsTitles[0]))
for (medal in medalTwo) {
      lists.add(AchievementTestModel(medal))
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, а у вас этот проект есть на гитхабе?

Comment: Проект мой личный и он закрытый. Если у вас будут вопросы по коду, какие места не понятны, спрашивайте)

Comment: ок, ну тут просто разбираться нужно на котлине не кодил просто, как разберусь будут вопросы)

Comment: Сейчас все новые проекты стараются стартовать на Kotlin. Посмотрите в его сторону и его плюсы

Comment: Да, думаю как закончу свой проект посмотреть в сторону Kotlin, а так посмотрел ваши проекты весьма впечатлен от вашего первого проекта. Если не секрет сколько подняли в $ на нём?

Comment: Есть возможность в Android Studio автоматически конвертировать код Java в Kotlin.  Насчет первого проекта, это он сейчас на таком этапе развития, а был порядком хуже  в разы. 
Насчет денежной части не скажу(я еще не выводил деньги). И проект я делал для портфолио, не думал что появятся пользователи.  Рекламу добавил для галочки в приложение, раньше её было очень много в приложение, сейчас уменьшил в несколько раз, поэтому и доход из них не большой.  Эти проекты, как хобби. В них я могу попробовать много разных штук